# Cinnamon icons don't appear

Tags: cinnamon

I installed cinnamon on ubuntu 12.04 and the menu icons do not appear, as well aprox. half of all icons do not appear.

[image]

Answer (score 24):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-icon-theme-full
```

Comment: Worked for me. I didn't even need to restart

Comment: Package gnome-icon-theme-full is not available, but is referred to by another package.

Answer (score 2):

That screenshot looks to me as if you're missing some icons- all the application icons appear to be there, but the icons representing categories of applications, as well as the actions to log out/shut down/etc, are not present.  Perhaps Cinnamon by default selects an icon set that isn't present on Ubuntu?  Try changing the icon theme in System Tools > System Settings > Themes to something like Ubuntu-Mono-Dark.

Answer (score -2):

open a ternimal window and enter:

```
gsettings set org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons true
```